# parsing XML String having same tag name using XmlPullParser in Android

Tags: android, xml

```
<ArrayOfArtist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<Artist>
<place>1</place>
<Albums>
<Album>
<SongNames>
<string>foo</string>
<string>bar</string>
<string>baz</string>
 </SongNames>
 </Album>
 </Albums>
 <Name>Mr Guy</Name>
 </Artist>
 <Artist>
 <place>2</place>
 <Albums>
 <Album>
 <SongNames>
 <string>green</string>
<string>orange</string>
<string>red</string>
 </SongNames>
 </Album>
 </Albums>
 <Name>Mr Buddy</Name>
 </Artist>
 <Artist>
 <place>3</place>
 <Albums>
 <Album>
 <SongNames>
 <string>brown</string>
 <string>pink</string>
 <string>blue</string>
 </SongNames>
 </Album>
 <Album>
 <SongNames>
 <string>apple</string>
 <string>orange</string>
 <string>pear</string>
 </SongNames>
 </Album>
 </Albums>
 <Name>Mr Friend</Name>
 </Artist>
 </ArrayOfArtist>
```

what i need is to parse the XML above and print the place,name and the song names for each artist.

the problem is that for each artist i am only getting the last song name

this is what i tried. Album is a class having String name and place and Songname.

```
                ArrayList<Album> products = null;   
                Album a=null;
                 while(xpp.getEventType() !=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                     String name=null;
                     switch (xpp.getEventType()){
                     case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                        products = new ArrayList();
                         break;
                     case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                         name = xpp.getName();
                         Log.e(TAG,"name is"+xpp.getName());
                         if (xpp.getName().equals("ArrayOfArtist")){
                             Log.e(TAG,"herehere");
                             a = new Album();
                         } else if (a != null){
                             if (name.equals("Artist")){
                                 Log.e(TAG,"artart");
                                 }
                             if (name.equals("place")){
                                 Log.e(TAG,"placeplace");
                                a.place = xpp.nextText();
                             }
                             else if (name.equals("Name")){
                                 Log.e(TAG,"namename");
                                 a.name = xpp.nextText();
                             }
                            else if (name.equals("string")){
                                         Log.e(TAG,"songssongs");
                                         a.seSongs(xpp.nextText());
                                     }  
                         }
                         break;

                     case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                         name = xpp.getName();
                         if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("ArrayOfArtist") && a != null){

                             products.add(a);
                         } 
             } 
                     xpp.next();
                 }
                 printProducts(products);
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }

   }
}
private void printProducts(ArrayList<Album> products)
{
    String content = "";
    Iterator<Album> it = products.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Log.e(TAG,"hete");
        Album currProduct  = it.next();
        content = content + "name :" +  currProduct.name + "\n";
        content = content + "place :" +  currProduct.place + "\n";
        content = content + "Songnames :" +  currProduct.Songname + "\n";

    }

    TextRecieved.setText("content is: "+content);
}
```